# Changing the login wallpaper in 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus)

Tags: 16.04, unity, lightdm, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I know the web is full of solution related to the question, but unfortunately none of them are working in my case. Many of them are also quite outdated. :(

Currently a custom photo (from /usr/share/backgrounds/photo.jpg) is set on my logon screen, but I dont find in any config file where I could change it. I have already ran the dconf-editor as different users, as it is suggested, to set the path in com.canonical.unity-greeter.background. Checked different relevant config files, but changing the path has no effect. Draw-user-backgrounds is unchecked.

some info:

- OS: 16.04.1
- encrypted home, but the path is set to /usr/share/backgrounds  /some_photo.jpg with dcont-editor
- owner of the custom photos are set to root:root, permission 777
- using different wallpaper rotating applications (webilder and variety), I hope they dont mess up anything.
- Compiz is installed (Its not really clear yet, if it could be a relevant component)
- I used to experiment with xfce desktop environment, which replaced unity-greeter with its lightdm. After that I purged xfce and lightdm,
  and restored unity-greeter. I hope it was clear restore.
- and Ubuntu-tweek-tool is no more available in 16.04, as I know.

Well now I am out ideas. Thank you for responses!

Comment: The solution I found changes it for each user separately, is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: No. What you have meant is the lockscreen wallpaper. (after the user already logged in) What I mean is the login screen wallpaper. (right after boot, before any user would logged in)

Comment: I tried that i wasn't able to change it. But keeps looking for the solution!